# Two exact same implementations of an interface are giving different .hashCode() results

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I've an interface like this-

```
public interface myInterface {
    String getMyString();
}
```

And two implementations like this-

```
class test implements myInterface {

        @Override
        public String getMyString() {
            return "1,2";
        }
    }

class test2 implements myInterface {

        @Override
        public String getMyString() {
            return "1,2";
        }
    }
```

When I create new instnaces of these two clasess and do .hashCode I get different values for hashCode. Why so?

```
test test = new test();
test2 test2 = new test2();

System.out.println(test.hashCode());
System.out.println(test2.hashCode());
```

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: What makes you think that they should be the same?

Comment: Why do you think they should be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from JavaDoc of `Object#hashCode()`

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Unless you have overridden `hashCode()`, what described above will be the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If three comments didn't tip you to your problem, you have different classes that you didn't override the `hashCode` method to actually make your classes have the same hashcode using your interface's method.

Answer (score 1):

Becasuse they are two different objects,you need to overwrite hashcode method if you gonna let them be the same.